# Rebooting 3ea Pi4 using netmiko

Tags: raspberry-pi, netmiko

from netmiko import ConnectHandler

ip_num=['192.168.0.101','192.168.0.102','192.168.0.103']

for i in ip_num:
pi4 = {
'device_type':'linux',
'ip' : i,
'username' : 'pi',
'password' : '12345678',
'secret' : 'True',
'port' : '22'
}
net_connect = ConnectionHandler(**pi4)
net_connect.enable()
net_connect.send_command("sudo reboot")
net_connect.disconnect()

this is my code.
The first pi 4 reboots fine.  After that I get a readtimeout error.  I also want the next 2 devices to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Without traceback it is hard to be sure, but most likely `send_command` cannot verify the execution of the command. Try `send_command("sudo reboot", cmd_verify=False)`.

https://ktbyers.github.io/netmiko/docs/netmiko/index.html